# My mainBall class wont repaint when i press a key

Tags: java, applet, awt, keypress, keydown

I created a class that draws a ball on a screen and my goal is to move it with the keys, but the ball stays in one spot. the coordinates of the ball change according to the key presses but not the actual ball itself

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class game extends Applet implements Runnable
{
    static final int WIDTH = 450;
    static final int HEIGHT =  450;
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

    public static long NEW_DOT_FREQ = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3);
    public long lastUpdateTime;
    public long timeSinceLastNewDot;


    public ArrayList<Ball> BALLS;

    Color[] color = {Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.magenta, Color.black};
    int colorIndex;

    static final int NUM_OF_BALLS = 4;

    int i;
    int t;

    MainBall mainBall = new MainBall(100, 100, 10, 10, 100, 100, 0, 0);

    Thread updateTime = new updateTime();

    public void start()
    {
        lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();//start main game

        updateTime.start();
    }

    public void updateGame()
    {
        //Get the current time
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Calculate how much time has passed since the last update
        long elapsedTime = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
        //Store this as the most recent update time
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

        //Create a new dot if enough time has passed
        //Update the time since last new dot was drawn
        timeSinceLastNewDot += elapsedTime;

        if (timeSinceLastNewDot >= NEW_DOT_FREQ)
        {
            int newX = randomNumber();
            int newY = randomNumber();

            debugPrint("New dot created at x:" + newX + ", y:" + newY + ".");

            BALLS.add(new Ball(newX, newY, 20, 20));

            timeSinceLastNewDot = 0;
        }
    }

    private void debugPrint(String value)
    {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public class updateTime extends Thread implements Runnable
    {
        public void run()
        {
            for(t = 0; ; t++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }
    }

    public int randomNumber()
    {
        return (int)(Math.random() * 400);
    }

    public int getRandomColor()
    {
        return (int)(Math.random() * 6);
    }

    public class MainBall
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;
        int xpos = 100;
        int ypos = 100;
        int xspeed = 0;
        int yspeed = 0;

        public MainBall(int x, int y, int width, int height, int xpos, int ypos, int xspeed, int yspeed)
        {
            this.x = 100;
            this.y = 100;
            this.width = 10;
            this.height = 10;
            this.xpos = 100;
            this.ypos = 100;
            this.xspeed = 0;
            this.yspeed = 0;
        }

        public void paintMainBall(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
            g.drawString(xpos + ", " + ypos, 20, 40);
        }
    }//mainBall

    class Ball
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;

        public Ball(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }//end ball

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(color[getRandomColor()]);
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        }//end paint


    }//ball class

    public void update(Graphics g)//double buffer don't touch!!
    {
        if(dbImage == null)
        {
            dbImage = createImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        }

        dbg.setColor(getBackground());
        dbg.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

        dbg.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(dbg);

        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public boolean keyDown (Event e, int key)
    {
        if(key == Event.LEFT)
        {
            mainBall.xspeed = -5;
            mainBall.yspeed = 0;
        }

        if(key == Event.RIGHT)
        {
            mainBall.xspeed = 5;
            mainBall.yspeed = 0;
        }

        if(key == Event.UP)
        {
            mainBall.yspeed = -5;
            mainBall.xspeed = 0;
        }

        if(key == Event.DOWN)
        {
            mainBall.yspeed = 5;
            mainBall.xspeed = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            repaint();

            if (mainBall.xpos < 1)
            {
                mainBall.xpos = 449;
            }

            if (mainBall.xpos > 449)
            {
                mainBall.xpos = 1;
            }
            if (mainBall.ypos < 1)
            {
                mainBall.ypos = 449;
            }

            if (mainBall.ypos > 449)
            {
                mainBall.ypos = 1;
            }
            mainBall.ypos += mainBall.yspeed;
            mainBall.xpos += mainBall.xspeed;
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){}
        }
      }

    public void init()
    {
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        BALLS = new ArrayList<Ball>();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        g.drawString("time: " + t, 20, 20);

        mainBall.paintMainBall(g);

        for (Ball ball : BALLS)
        {
            ball.paint(g);
        }

        updateGame();
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I created a class.."*  This code looks more like 'you got it from somewhere', where 'somewhere' is 1999.  It uses an `Applet` and deprecated methods such as `keyDown(Event,int)`.  The best advice I can offer is - put the code back where you found it, and visit the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and specifically the [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) & [key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) parts.  Also, develop desktop apps. 1st, much simpler than applets.

Answer (score 1):

You update the xPos/yPos values of the ball, but never the x/y values

```
public void paintMainBall(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("PaintMainBall");
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
    g.drawString(xpos + ", " + ypos, 20, 40);
}
```